# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification network pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am hosting the image in other storage-S3, not Firebase Hosting or Google Cloud.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-nesaging/android/send-emage?hl

When I checked this document, I sent an image to the URL, Even if I send Image in other storage URLs, not Google Cloud Products, do I have to pay a network bandwidth cost at Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Firebase Cloud Messaging Network Pricing I don't understand well, so I ask questions.

search about it many times and, nothing found about the answer I was looking for

Comment: The link in your page doesn't work, so you might want to check and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Cloud Messaging itself is completely free of charge, as you can see by its inclusion in the list of <kbd>No-cost Products</kbd> products on the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

> if I send Image in other storage URLs, not Google Cloud Products, do I have to pay a network bandwidth cost at Firebase Cloud Messaging?

No, there is never a charge for bandwidth consumed by Cloud Messaging. Only if you choose to include a URL to an image in Cloud Storage or Firebase Hosting will you be charged for the bandwidth used to retrieve those images. If you host the images on another service, no charges from Firebase will apply for them.